# How to iterate Sharepoint site's document library items via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to iterate through items under a document lib and a folder under a document lib in Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API V1.0 and Beta too.

I can list doc lib using following request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/FOA/BD:/drives
```

but I can't iterate through items under a specific drive under above path.

After a long research I tried with beta all the way to list all items under a drive still no result:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/
```

I followed [Get an item in a list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listItem_get), but still no success.

Comment: Ravi, to enumerate the children in a drive, you need to access the children collection of the drive... something like this:
```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/FOA/BD:/drives/{drive-id}/root/children``` Is that what you're doing? Are you getting an error when trying this?

Comment: will check and let you know.

Comment: i tried with suggested url as follows:(no success only errors)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydoamin.sharepoint.com‌​:/FOA/BD:/drives/b!VCvM../root/childre‌​n
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydoamin.sharepoint.com‌​:/FOA/BD:/drives/budget/root/childre‌​n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. Using the first link getting the list of drives, copy the drive-id of the drive which you want to retrieve the documents. Then you would use the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/children
```

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614072/6559330) with more detail for getting children items using Graph v1.0.