# Query for files in OneDrive returns empty list

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, adal

I want to create a simple Python utility that interacts with files on OneDrive. Right now I'm using my company account (so I have no access to admin settings or any detailed insight into OneDrive/Sharepoint/Azure configuration).

After quick googling session it seemed that Microsoft Graph is the way to go. I started with copying [the sample app](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app) and once I verified that basic functionality is working (it shows the name from my profile, etc.) I tried adding a simple call to `me/drive/root/children` in order to list files in the root directory. And I am unable to get it working.

No matter what I do, server returns the following:

```
{'@odata.context': "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('my_oid')/drive/root/children", 'value': []}
```

This problem happened to a [few](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/776) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687268/list-children-api-doesnt-give-all-the-children-of-the-drive-folder) before, so I tried to follow their footpaths. So far I checked that:

- Application has seemingly correct static permissions: `Files.Read`, `Files.Read.All`, `Files.ReadWrite`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `openid`, `profile`, `User.Read` and even 
  `Sites.ReadWrite.All`
- These permissions do not require administrator's approval, so I guess they should work
- `me/drive/root/?expand=children` returns correct data with filesystem info, etc.
- `me/drive/root/children?$whatif` returns correct URL for the query: `https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{username}/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children`
- If I open this URL in a browser with active OneDrive session it returns JSON with list of files in the root folder (so it's indeed correct)
- Messing with `adal` library and adding `scope=files.readwrite.all` to all OAuth queries (no change).
- using `/user/{oid}/drive/root/children` query (no change, `?$whatif` suggests this maps to the same sharepoint URL)

None of this worked. What could be missing here?

Edit: What is missing is user consent - I've added permissions but the system never asked me about the changes after login attempt. The solution provided in the comments works - you just need to open URL crafted like this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={your_client_id}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&state=12345&prompt=consent`

Agree for the new permissions and voila! Great job MS.

Comment: After updating the permissions, did you grant user consent again? If not, you can force user consent through a url request. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your_client_id}
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&state=12345
&prompt=consent` Refer to my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070562/10504999

Comment: @CaiyiJu I tried removing token cache and logging in again, but I was never asked about additional permissions. Finally, after using your URL it started to work. This is crazy. Thank you, I'd never figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the permissions, users and/or admins will have to consent again.You can force user consent through a url request or just click 'grant admin consent button' in azure portal.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id={your_client_id} &response_type=code &response_mode=query &resource=https://graph.microsoft.com &state=12345 &prompt=consent`