# Microsoft Graph API - How to upload attachments to a list item

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810109/how-to-attachment-a-file-to-an-item-in-sharepoint-using-microsoft-graph) with not much success.

The documentation is totally unclear too. It implies that to create a new list item one would do the [following](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/listitem_create). But doesn't give a specific example on attachments.

The [listitem documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/listitem) has a sneaky caveat right at the end which says that files/document libraries are treated as driveitems:

*For document libraries, the driveItem relationship exposes the listItem as a driveItem*

Right, so does that mean that all files are then related to driveitems? It seems closer as the [driveitem docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content) talk about the following example (indicating site-related content which is SharePoint)

*PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content*

But the above route doesn't specify a list-id either an item-id. So how does that fit in?

Which route do we hit to upload attachments on a list item? I have tried numerous requests:

PUT - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/2696fba7-2cc5-482f-805e-a3dbf853e5e9/items/1/content

PUT - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/items/1/createUploadSession (not list id though?)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285403/upload-file-to-sharepoint-drive-using-microsoft-graph

Answer (score -1):

To upload an small item (<4MB) into a Sharepoint Online document library or list which is not the default library, you can youse the following url syntax:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE-ID}/drives/{DRIVE-ID}/root:/{FILENAME}:/content

- {SITE-ID}: the id of sp site
- {DRIVE-ID}: the id of drive (document library or list)
- {FILENAME}: the name of the fie to upload

The "/root:" after the drive id is the important point.

Comment: The question is about list item attachments, not drive documents.