# MS Graph http Web request string

Tags: http, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to upload a file to my Share Point online's document directory. I already successfully managed log on tokens and associated code. All I'm looking for is the actual Http Web request string I can use in MS Graph explorer. I can then translate that string to my needs.
I get to this point in MS Graph explorer....
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyRootsharepointsite/drives/MydriveID

I also understand the content needs to be an array of bytes, I'm totally stuck on https:// portion...

BTW I can easily do this to my one-drive account, but the same pathing does not work for SPO (office 365).

Answer (score 0):

PaulCr125

Based on the question you posted, my understanding is you want to use Microsoft Graph to upload a file to the SharePoint Online's document directory.If I misunderstood your question, please feel free let me know.

My initial suggestion is that you can try use this API: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{document directory's id}/root:/{Folder Name}/{File Name}:/content`.

Based on my test, we can create a stream of the file into the body of the request. And the steps of the solution resemble the following:

1. Get the document directory's id by the API below:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives`

The part of the response like this:

```
{

     "createdDateTime": "2018-06-26T15:06:46Z",

     "description": "",

     "id": {the directory's id},

     "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-08-14T05:29:44Z",

     "name": "Documents",

     "webUrl": "https://XX.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",

     "driveType": "documentLibrary",
}
```

2. Make a PUT request to the following URL:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{the directory's id}/root:/{Folder Name}/{File Name}:/content`

Note: Before initiating this request, we should set two required headers:

1) Authorization
2) Content-Type

For more detail, we can refer to the content of '[Upload or replace the contents of a DriveItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content#example-upload-a-new-file)' and [the question on the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285403/upload-file-to-sharepoint-drive-using-microsoft-graph).

Comment: I appreciate the response and I'm still struggling I'm getting a "Only one path can be specified in the URL" error.... I have my main company root site then a team site. I'll continue to try different combinations. Cannot  understand why its so difficult to document something like this.

Comment: Finally after 3 weeks of trying different things.... https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyCorporateSite/drives/MyDriveID/root:/Folder/SubFolder/1.txt:/content = byte array

Comment: Did the solution I provided solve your problem? If so, could you please mark this as answer.