# How to upload files to shared drive using graph explorer

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

With [this](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe/) graph explorer query, able to list all shared folders.

But, how to access a particular folder inside this and upload files to it?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285403/upload-file-to-sharepoint-drive-using-microsoft-graph) is used for uploading files to normal folders, how to do the same with shared folders?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks)

> DriveItems returned from the sharedWithMe action will always include the remoteItem facet which indicates they are items from a different drive. To access the shared DriveItem resource, you will need to make a request using the information provided in remoteItem in the following format:

So to access or upload to the shared folder, you need the ***remoteitem.parentReference.driveId*** and ***remoteItem.id*** then navigate the file tree normally for example just use [the upload file docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

To access the folder
*GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/remoteitem.parentReference.driveId/items/remoteItem.id*

Here is a curl to upload files to a shared folder

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/remoteitem.parentReference.driveId/items/remoteItem.id:/File.txt:/content' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ey...' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'Hello'
```

Comment: How to generate this  'Authorization: Bearer ey...'?

Comment: This depends on how you want to access graph and how you will authenticate. For the start, I recommend testing this using Graph Explorer which generates access tokens for you. Once ready, you can check [Getting started with MS Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) which guides on how to access graph.